# How to use Fourier cosine series to find coefficients of cos((2n+1) π x/L) series?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation

After solving a heat equation and applying the initial condition I need to find coefficients $a_n$ for following solution:

$$\phi(x,0) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \cos{\Big(\frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{L}}\Big) = f(x).$$

The function $f(x)$ for initial condition is:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 - x^2, & 0 \leq x \leq 1, \\
    0, & 1 < x < L. \end{cases}$$

I solved this by substituting $m=2n+1$ and using the Fourier cosine formula:
$$a_0 = \frac{1}{L} \int_0^L f(x) \ dx$$
$$a_n = \frac{2}{L} \int_0^L f(x) \cos{\Big(\frac{m \pi x}{L} \Big)} \ dx.$$

This formula works for approximating  $a_n \cos(m \pi x/L)$. You can see the upside-down parabola with maximum value of $y(0) = 1$, the same one as in the initial conditions:

[image: Fourier approximation cos(npi x)]

See interactive graph here:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/buwlinay71

However, when I substitute back $m=(2n + 1)$ and ignore $a_0$ the formula produces result that is $0.5$ of the desired amplitude. You can see the upside-down parabola, but its maximum value is $0.5$ instead of $1$.

[image: Fourier approximation cos((2n+1)pi x)]

Interactive graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mgdwcgxkof

I'm banging my head agains the wall for hours now checking my algebra and calculations seem correct. Did I make a conceptual mistake by using $m=2n+1$ and throwing away the $a_0$ coefficient? It bothers me that by replacing $m=2n+1$ I threw away the even terms of the series, and I suspect that this is what's causing this bug.

Comment: There is no constant coefficient because $m=2n+1$ is always odd, so your first integral is unnecessary (and also incorrect). The $a_0$ integral should be identical to the other $a_n$ integrals

Comment: @Dylan, yes, that's a problem. It seems I can't use the even extension here. I can't use the odd extension either, because it will give Fourier sin series. But I need the cosine term to match my PDE solution.

Comment: There is no problem here. The cosine series is always even. Only the frequencies are odd. Hence there's no constant term in the final solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your series solutions are incorrect (and also completely different series). The first one happens to match the given function out of luck. You sum should be something like

$$ f(x) = a_0\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right) + a_1 \cos\left(\frac{3\pi x}{L}\right) + a_2 \cos\left(\frac{5\pi x}{L}\right) + \dots $$

Notice there is no constant term here, since all the frequencies are odd. It seems the indexing threw you off since $a_0$ corresponds to the first odd frequency, and so on.

Your first series appears to be a different Fourier expansion including even frequencies ($\cos (\frac{2\pi x}{L})$ and so on), which is incorrect.

Your second series only contains odd frequencies, so it's much closer to the actual solution.

I would suggest you redo your integrals this way (no substitutions needed), and note that

$$ a_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_0^L f(x) \cos \left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{L} \right)\ dx $$

for **all** values of $n$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've calculated the $a_n$ using your suggested formula. It gave me the same wrong result, it is 1/2 of the amplitude I need. See Mathematica working here: https://ibb.co/iqqL4S

Comment: The problem is in your series. Cosines with only odd frequencies do not form a complete basis for your function space. You'd need to add the remaining even frequencies, or another sine series to properly represent the boundary function. I'd like to know what the initial PDE is, and see if you may be missing anything

Comment: @Evgenii For example, if your boundary conditions (I'm guessing) are $u_x(0,t) = u(L,t) = 0$, then your eigenfunction *should* be $$ g(x) = \cos \left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2L}\right) $$ which would form a complete solution space

Comment: My initial PDE is the standard heat equation $(U_t = U_{xx)$. And the boundary conditions are the ones you mentioned above.

Comment: And yes, my eigenfunction g(x) is the same as you wrote above, with 2L in the denominator.

Comment: I just replaced L=2L for this post. If I didn't do this, would it make a difference in the way we find the coefficients a_n?

Comment: It does make a difference. The correct integral is
$$ a_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_0^L f(x)\cos \left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2L}\right) dx  $$

Notice how the coefficients are twice as much as if you just replace $L \to 2L$, since the normalization constant is for an interval of length $L$.

Comment: Next time, be sure to add the full context to your question, even if you think it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much @Dylan, I was so confused. :)